# Software to fix broken videos (MP4 and MOV specifically)

Tags: video, video-editing, mp4

I have some corrupt MP4 and MOV files that I'd like to try to repair.
I've tried converting it in VLC and also in LosslessCut but they still won't play, and I've tried playing them in various players including VLC with the 'automatically fix broken videos' option selected to always and it still doesn't play.
I've downloaded a few video repair tools but apart from one they all only work with AVI files, and the one that does accept MP4 files just says there was no problem found.
I was close to giving up however fix.video does manage to repair the videos, the only problem is that they want $6 for each video which seems like a lot.
Can anyone please recommend an alternative to try? Preferably free would be great, thank you!

Edit: Untrunc kinda recovered the video but the frame rate was kinda weird and it ran very slowly, maybe I can fix that

Answer (score 1):

I personally use `ffmpeg` using command like:

```
ffmpeg -i input_file.mp4 -c fixes_input_file.mp4
```

This help me recover from repeated error with source files in DaVinci Resolve

Also I use (depend of the video) command in this way:

```
ffmpeg -i input_file.mp4 -c copy fixes_input_file.mp4
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll give this a shot! I didn't realise ffmpeg could repair files :)